# Confusion about naming conventions in emberjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Perhaps some folks just know the answer, but I am trying to understand the following:

Say you are declaring a view:

`App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({});`

Now referencing this view in `App.Router` results in the following error:

`router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('Foo')`

When I reference Foo the console states: `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The name you supplied Foo did not resolve to a controller FooController`

I could not find anywhere in the docs explaining the args. Perhaps the person who downvoted could actually contribute to the solution.

Comment: "foo" in `.connectOutlet('foo')` should be lowercase (not sure if this is strictly necessary), as I believe you had it before the edit. You need a controller too: `App.FooController = Ember.Controller.extend({});` (It wasn't I who downvoted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect an outlet, the router looks for both a controller and a view the having the same name as the one supplied. In the example you listed, the router is looking for a FooController and a FooView, and is not finding the controller. If you would like to specify more details you can pass an options object with the view, controller and context, like so:

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet( {
           outletName: 'master',
           controller: 'fooController',
           view: 'fooView',
           context: data
        });
```

From the documentation:

```
connectOutlet: function(name, context) {
// Normalize arguments. Supported arguments:
//
// name
// name, context
// outletName, name
// outletName, name, context
// options
//
// The options hash has the following keys:
//
//   name: the name of the controller and view
//     to use. If this is passed, the name
//     determines the view and controller.
//   outletName: the name of the outlet to
//     fill in. default: 'view'
//   viewClass: the class of the view to instantiate
//   controller: the controller instance to pass
//     to the view
//   context: an object that should become the
//     controller's `content` and thus the
//     template's context.
```

edit: grammar and code format

Comment: @ buuda I more or less came across this in the updated guides on emberjs website - thanks for providing an answer I could use.