# Emberjs: Router: Get another controller to connect outlets

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application"> 
{{view App.UiMenuView}}
{{view App.UiMainContainerView}}
{{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="uiMainContainer">
<div id="uiMainContainer">
<div id="uiMainContainerSidebar">
{{#view App.SidebarView}}
<ul id="uiMainContainerSidebarList">
<li><a {{bindAttr href="view.tasksUrl"}}>Tasks</a></li>
<li><a {{bindAttr href="view.milestonesUrl"}}>Milestones</a></li>
<li><a {{bindAttr href="view.projectsUrl"}}>Projects</a></li>
<li><a {{bindAttr href="view.customersUrl"}}>Customers</a></li>
</ul>
{{/view}}
</div>
<div id="uiMainContainerContainer">{{outlet}}</div>
</div>
</script>
```

I am wondering if there's a way to address the specifically the `outlet` from `uiMainContainer`? I tried something like:

```
test: Em.Route.extend({
            route: '/test',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                //router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({ name: 'test' });
                router.get('uiMainContainerController').connectOutlet({ name: 'test'});
            }
        })
```

This approach, however, seems to do nothing.

Comment: Could you post a more complete fiddle please ? Seeing your code here, this seems to be right. Just keep in mind that the hash passed to the connectOutlet is important (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832864/confusion-about-naming-conventions-in-emberjs), and if you miss something in the naming convention, nothing could be displayed

Comment: @sly7_7 http://jsfiddle.net/6HCgz/

Comment: @sly7_7 I still couldn't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I'm looking into that... but I'm at the office ^^

Comment: It seems thaht you have to chain outlets, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/6HCgz/6/